# Django template static dynamically

Tags: django-templates

In normal way using static files in Django template we can use:

```
<img src="{% static 'img/sim/simcard1.png' %}">
```

My question and ask about help is, how to generate ID with simcardID.png dynamically -depend of variables in view.

```
<img src="{% static 'img/sim/simcard{{ simid }}.png' %}">
```

give:

```
<img src="/static/img/sim/simcard%7B%7B%20simid%20%7D%7D.png">
```

Anybody help?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="{% static 'img/sim/simcard{{ simid }}.png' %}">
```

Should be replaced with:

```
<img src="/static/img/sim/simcard{{ simid }}.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old topic but if anyone reads it, you can do that with `with` :

```
{% with 'img/sim/simcard'|add:simid|add:'.png' as img_static %}
    <img src="{% static img_static %}">
{% endwith %}
```